# How do I stop an inifinite loop in GMail Offline

Tags: google-chrome, email, gmail, google-chrome-extensions

When I try to use GMail Offline in Chrome it goes into an infinite loop, requests alternating between https://mail.google.com/mail/mu/mp/411/?mui=ca and https://mail.google.com/mail/mu/mp/511/?mui=ca.

I found several articles dating back to 2009 that say this problem can occur when switching back and forth between Google accounts, which I was doing when the problem started. However, trying the proposed solutions of clearing or disabling the cache and/or cookies had no effect.

I can still use the regular GMail. I have also tried logging into and out of the online GMail accounts and that didn't help either.

Comment: Did you try clearing the chrome cache and re-installing Gmail offline ?

Comment: I would backup your Chrome profile, wipe the profile, and see if the problem still exists.  You can then slowly merge the two profiles to determine the conflict.